# Multiple linear regression - interpretation diagnostic plots

Tags: multiple-regression, linear-model, diagnostic

I am learning so bear with me.

**Aim:** I am trying to figure out if my data fit the criteria for multiple linear regression.

**Context:** My model has two numeric and four categoric variables.

```
kiva_model <- lm(lender_count ~
                   loan_usd+ #Numeric
                   sector+ #Categoric 11 levels
                   term_in_months+ #Numeric
                   borrower_genders+ #Categoric 5 levels
                   repayment_interval+ #Categoric 3 levels
                   country_code, #Categoric 59 levels
                    data=kiva_omit)
```

Sample size is 504,528.

I checked the correlation between the three numeric variables as follows:

[image]

`loan_usd` is a strong predictor or `lender_count`.

I have made plots to assess:
a) Linearity of numerical variables
b) nearly normal residuals
c) constant variability.

**The images show the before (above) and after (below) of outlier removal using `cooks_distance<4/n`.**

I cannot figure out if this is acceptable enough to proceed with my analysis or if I have to further manipulate the data prior the final regression.

To summarise my main concerns:

- Conical shape in `term_in_months` vs. residuals.
- Slight S-shape in Normal probability plot.
- Strong line in Residuals vs. predicted.

**a) Linearity of numerical variables**

[image]

[image]

**b) Nearly normal residuals**

[image]

**c) Constant variability**

Residuals vs. predicted

[image]

Absolute value of residuals vs. predicted

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to see the images. Based on what you have mentioned, Conical shape between **term_in_months**(variable) and residuals implies violation of linearity. Try to use non linear relationship between target variable (**lender_count**) and **term_in_months**. for example: use some polynomial form of order 2,3 for **term_in_months**. Slight S-Shape may be ignored if it is not statistically significant.If your features(Variables) are correlated (causing multicollinearity), you can use Principal component analysis to decorrelate them. 
You can check all the assumptions by doing statistical test as well. for instance, **Kolmogorov-Smirnov test** and **Anderson-Darling test** are used for normality. For independents residuals, you can use **Durbin-Watson test**. You can check 
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/07/deeper-regression-analysis-assumptions-plots-solutions/.

In nutshell, try to transform your data. Box-cox transformation may help you in resolving this.